# edit and update function in controller for has_one active record association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to have a better understanding how to properly call for the update action for a `has_one` relationship. I'm receiving the following error

> NameError (uninitialized constant User::Companyinfos): app/controllers/companyinfos_controller.rb:3:in `edit'

I want help fixing my controller, but also is there a good article to read about controllers when using the association in the database. I'm new and trying to get better.

**user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
   enum role: [:startup, :investor]
   # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
   # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
   devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

   has_one :photos, dependent: :destroy
   has_one :companyinfos, dependent: :destroy
   validates :name, presence: true
   validates :role, presence: true
   after_create :add_companyinfos


   def add_companyinfos
    Companyinfo.create(user: self)
   end
```

end

I'm using after_create becuase I only want the users to beable to edit company info.

**companyinfo.rb**

```
class Companyinfo < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**companyinfos_controller.rb**

```
class CompanyinfosController < ApplicationController
  def edit
    @companyinfo = User.find(current_user.id).companyinfos
  end

  def update
    @companyinfo = Companyinfo.find(current_user.id).companyinfos
    if @companyinfo.update(companyinfo_params)
        flash[:notice] = "Saved ..."
    else
        flash[:alert] = "cannot save"
    end
    render 'edit'
  end

private

  def companyinfo_params
     params.require(:company_basic).permit(:CompanyStage)
  end
end
```

**edit.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for :companyinfo do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :CompanyStage %>
    <%= f.submit "save", class: "btn btn-success" %>
<% end %>
```

**routes.rb**

```
  resources :users, only: [:show] do
    resources :photos, only: [:create, :destroy]
    resources :companyinfos, only: [:edit, :update]
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `has_one` relationship should be `companyinfo` not `companyinfos`, same for `photos` model and to learn about model associations in rails, [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) should be a good place to start

Comment: Yes, that worked. I didn't notice that before. When using has_one it's singular, so no s on the end. Thanks!

Comment: glad to be of help